# Aproveitar resultado

Tags: php, laravel

Gostaria de aproveitar o resultado de uma consulta em outra função quando solicitado

Por exemplo:

**Controller**

```
 public function funcao1(Request $request){
       $myObj = DB::select("SELECT * FROM myTable");
       return view('myView');
    }
```

Aí gostaria de utilizar esse objeto $myObj em outra função quando viesse da minha view, através de um click ou via ajax

**Ajax**

```
var form = $('<form action="{{ route('myRoute') }}"> method="post"'+
             '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}"'> 
             '</form>')
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

**Controller**

Nessa parte, que eu gostaria de aproveitar o objeto que eu setei na primeira função

```
public function funcao2(Request $request){
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($myObj);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

Minha rota ficaria

```
Route::post('/obj', ['as' => 'myRoute', 'uses' => 'MyController@funcao2']) ;
```

Comment: Cada requisição é única, não tem como reaproveitar dessa forma, o que você poderia fazer é um cache da informação por algum tempo, mas, isso também tem que ser bem pensado ...

Answer (score 1):

Por estar usando o Laravel, vejo que tem muita coisa errada no seu código.

Mas o que poderia ser feito, respondendo objetivamente, seria usar o `$this` para atribuir o valor a ele.

Assim:

```
class MeuController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myObject = DB::table('...');
    }


    public function funcao1()
    {
        return view('xxx', ['myObject' => $this->myObject]);
    }

    public function funcao2()
    {
        print_r($this->myObject);
    }
}
```